# Magsafe "L" light takes few seconds before turning off after being unplugged

Tags: power, magsafe

I've bought the 85w Apple adapter from Amazon warehouse (used). It works fine but when I unplug it, the orange light stays on for few more seconds before turning off, while the old adapter turns off instantly. It only happens if i leave it plugged for few mins. I also tested it on another MBP and it does the same.
Is it faulty/should I return it?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing more than capacitor discharge.

The larger the capacitance, the longer it takes to dissipate once the power source is removed.

It's a power smoothing feature, not just in laptop chargers but many other electrical items.
Without it, small power fluctuations in the mains would cause computer glitches or crashes - or in simpler structures like LED lighting, flickering.

Comment: Oh that's why, i get it now! Just... why doesnt the other (older but perfectly functioning) adapter do the same?

Comment: They may just have a slightly different component design inside.